# How do I make my hitTestObject() more precise?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, collision-detection

I'm doing some collision detection with a circle and a square and whenever the circle comes in contact with the square it bounces away changing its X coordinate by *-1. However, the Hit Area of the circle is a square, so even when it collides with the white area around the circle , the affect still occurs.

My question is, is there a way to modify the hit area to closer resemble my circle?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmap hit testing is pixel based (instead of boundary-based, like Sprite-based hit testing), so it is inherently more precise.

[Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest%28%29) are the Adobe docs on it.

[Here](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/) is a nice tutorial on it.

And here is a nice code snippet on it:

```
if (firstObjectBitmapData.hitTest(new Point(firstObject.x, firstObject.y), 255, secondObjectBitmapData, new Point(secondObject.x, secondObject.y), 255))
{
    trace("hit!");
}
```

Comment: you should briefly describe the content of the links - such a classic question is pretty vulnerable to "dead" links in the future

Comment: @blaizor I did briefly describe the contents of the links. I explained what bitmap hit testing does, suggested using it, and I provided a working code sample. Even if both links died, the code sample still answers this question. I can't copy/paste an entire API doc into a SO answer.