# Collision Detection in Flash Functionalities? (hitTestObject)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, collision-detection

- Hello, so I've been recently using `hitTestObject` to detect collisions in an android app I'm making. After testing for a bit, I realized that the game was detecting "fake" collisions. What I mean by this is that it was detecting a collisions **not** when the pixels of an object(s) are touching, but (after doing a bit of research) I found out that the *boxes* of the objects where colliding. So I had the game stop with a collision, and this is how it looks like:

[image]

I tried outlining the two object's boxes, for clarity. As you can see their *boxes* are touching. Is there any way to have it detect when *pixels* collide?

- I assume there would be something online for this, but I do not know what. The game is programmed through the actions window, not a class files, so there is no package, nor class, and any collision detection "function" online, that need a class to work, probably won't work here.

**Anyway:** is there any way in actionscript-3 to detect *pixels* colliding, and if so. What function and/or command could I use for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976222/as3-hittestobject-collision-not-registering-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly notice, hit areas in hitTestObject are by default rectangular, as they use the bounding box.

You can test against the object's actual shape on a point-by-point basis using...

```
hitTestPoint(someobject.x, someobject.y, true);
```

(See the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29).)

For custom-shaped hit areas, you can also use bitmap hit testing. ([See accepted answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533626/how-do-i-make-my-hittestobject-more-precise))

Comment: With the hitTestPoint object, doesn't it check just that x and y coords? So like if the edge of a box hit the edge of a circle, it wouldn't detect it if I set the .x and .y coords to the center of the circle?

Comment: That it is on a point-by-point basis. Nothing much. You could also use the second method I linked to, if that works better. Beyond that, that's all you can do for hit tests.

Comment: Thanks! I did a bit of research and it seems that the bitmap thing is great for me, although I don't understand it :3

Answer (score 1):

Collision detection has been a major hurdle for coders for years. There are many different methods for detecting collisions:

- hitTestPoint:
- pixel collisions by color
- separating axis theorem:http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html
- BitmapData
- and of course the infamous hitTestObject

I found hitTestPoint to be the most practical. However, in your case you may want to go along the lines of BitmapData:
http://www.freeactionscript.com/2011/08/as3-pixel-perfect-collision-detection/

Cheers,
Drake Swartzy

Comment: I have previously tried the detection kit from freeactionscript, but had some errors. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score -1):

you can do it this way
    `if(instanceName1.hitTestObject(instancename2) == true)
    {
    //execute the code you want
    }`

instanceName1 and 2 are the given name in the porgram

Comment: This won't work because hitTestObject always tests to the bounding box.

Comment: That is what I have been doing. This is how I get that error.