# how to use droptarget in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2, droptarget

I need to convert this AS2 code to AS3.

```
on (release)
 {

    stopDrag();
    this.MOR1.zzz.gotoAndStop(1);

    if (this._droptarget == "/lcd5") {

        this.MOR1.zzz.shekl.gotoAndStop(1);
        _root.nor.gotoAndStop(3);
    } else {

        this.MOR1.zzz.shekl.gotoAndStop(4);
        _root.nor.gotoAndStop(2);
    }

    if (this._droptarget == "/lcd1") {

        setProperty(this, _x, -731.7);
        setProperty(this, _y, 626.4);
    }
}
```

Please help me. Thank you...

Comment: Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/4eBcq/

Comment: Rule #1 of programming: do your own work. You'll need to do the conversion yourself. I'm just saying that in case you thought someone here would do it for you. If you planned to do it yourself, that's good. I answered below with some links to get you started on accomplishing your goal in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're going to need to start using [event listeners](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e54.html).

Now to the main issue. dropTarget [appeared to stop working in an update recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032442/adobe-air-3-2-glitch). I'm not entirely sure why.

Thus, you're going to need to change approach. Instead of droptarget, use one of the following...

- [DisplayObject hitTestPoint()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestPoint%28%29)
- [DisplayObject hitTestObject()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#hitTestObject%28%29) (beware, [this one matches
  to the bounding box of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069020/collision-detection-in-flash-functionalities-hittestobject/21069434#21069434), NOT to the object's actual
  shape)
- [Bitmap hitTest()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest%28%29).

I recommend hitTestPoint() out of the three, but the final decision is up to you.