# ActionScript 2.0 to ActionScript 3.0 Conversion: Drag and Drop 1 object to multiple targets?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement, actionscript, drag-and-drop

I'm developing an educational game that features multiple choice questions where the player must drag and drop a "selector" onto one of 3 answer panels.

This is some code from a previous version of the game that uses ActionScript 2.0

```
Object(_root).selector.origX = Object(_root).selector._x;
Object(_root).selector.origY = Object(_root).selector._y;
Object(_root).selector.onPress = function ()
{
    Object(_root).selector.startDrag();
};
Object(_root).selector.onRelease = function ()
{
    Object(_root).selector.stopDrag();
    if (eval(Object(_root).selector._droptarget) == Object(_root).target1)
    {
        stopAllSounds ();
        gotoAndPlay(1017); //Go to Game Over Screen
        Object(_root).selector._x = Object(_root).target1._x;
        Object(_root).selector._y = Object(_root).target1._y;
    }
    else if (eval(Object(_root).selector._droptarget) == Object(_root).target2)
    {
        stopAllSounds ();
        gotoAndPlay(1017); //Go to Game Over Screen
        Object(_root).selector._x = Object(_root).target2._x;
        Object(_root).selector._y = Object(_root).target2._y;
    }
    else if (eval(Object(_root).selector._droptarget) == Object(_root).target3)
    {
        play (); //Go to Next Question
        Object(_root).selector._x = Object(_root).target3._x;
        Object(_root).selector._y = Object(_root).target3._y;
    }
    else //Return selector back to original position if dropped anywhere outside of targets
    {
        Object(_root).selector._x = Object(_root).selector.origX;
        Object(_root).selector._y = Object(_root).selector.origY;
    }
};
```

What I was wondering is how this code would look like when converted to ActionScript 3.0. What adjustments would I have to make in order for this block of code to work using AS 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

From this page: http://www.kirupa.com/flash/easy_drag_drop_flash_as3.htm

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging, true);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging, true);

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent) {
dragger.startDrag();
}

function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent) {
dragger.stopDrag();
}
```

The two this.addEventListener would be changed to selector.addEventListener, and you would substitute dragger.start/stopDrag() to what you'll learn from the page I link below.

You would then add detection of the dropTarget, as described here: [how to use droptarget in AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071984/how-to-use-droptarget-in-as3)